# How to remove these gaps between lines in intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Recently I started seeing these lines gaps between lines in IntelliJ Idea and strangely this is only happening for variable declaration.

I tried reducing line height but that is not working.

How to switch it off?
[Image of gaps between lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjErp.png)

Comment: Please check "Blank lines" section in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java". Probably you have blank lines around field configured?

Comment: I tried this but this is not fixing it.

Comment: Have you run code reformat after changing settings? Could you please try to use default code style. Will it help?

Comment: I have restored it to default and also tried reformatting after the change it is not working.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new projects/files as well? Do you use IDEA 14?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-221.5080.210, built on April 12, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 6288M
Cores: 10
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (221.5080.126)

Kotlin: 221-1.6.20-release-285-IJ5080.210


This is the IntelliJ I am using.
Right now it is happening for all the projects either new or old.

Comment: Could you please try to temporarily disable custom plugins (10 Non-Bundled Plugins)?

Comment: Actually, it is Cores: 10 and 2 non bundled plugins which are idea.plugin.protoeditor and Kotlin: 221-1.6.20-release-285-IJ5080.210 I tried disabling these it is not working.

Comment: I also noticed that if I cut-paste these attributes this space is gone but after reopening the file it will again come back.

Comment: Please try to disable Editor>Inlay Hints>Code Vision

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Remove Unnecessary Line Spacing in Code Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069545/how-to-remove-unnecessary-line-spacing-in-code-editor)

Answer (score 5):

Please try to disable IntelliJ IDEA>Settings>Editor>Inlay Hints>Code Vision

Answer (score 0):

Just press Ctrl-Shift-A in Windows or Option-Command-L

Comment: Tried this multiple times this is not working. Please check the screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

Just press Ctrl-Shift-L in Windows or Option-Command-L on Mac OS